# Is it not possible to transform a feature from one featuredataset into another with arcgis toolbox?

Tags: arctoolbox

I am reprojecting datasets from the path1 to path2. The only difference is that the dataset is names differently and obviously has another coordinate system.

path1 = Datenbankverbindungen\VEKTOR.sde\GISVektor.DBO.Verkehr\GISVektor.DBO.VISPA_POINT
path2 = Datenbankverbindungen\VEKTOR.sde\GISVektor.DBO.Verkehr_ETRS\GISVektor.DBO.VISPA_POINT_ETRS
However, when the dataset has been successfully transformed with arctoolbox, the featureclass is saved outside the featuredataset and in the root directory of the database.

Is this normal?

yours,

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert, no this is not normal because you should be able to write the outputs of the geoprocessing operation to the feature dataset you specify. I assume that you have write privileges to write data into the feature dataset.

If you use the Project GP tool to perform the reprojection, be sure to specify in the output directory full path to the feature dataset as your output workspace directory. So, in your case it would be "Datenbankverbindungen\VEKTOR.sde\GISVektor.DBO.Verkehr_ETRS".

If you run the operation from a ModelBuilder with some batch iterating, just make sure again that the full path to the feature dataset is specified and it is not lost on its way. Another quick suggestion is to refresh the ArcSDE connection you work with, a feature class might be drawn in the root directory yet stored in the feature dataset, so refreshing the connection might help.